# How to access bookmark in a shape

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I have a bookmark placed inside a rectangle shape in a Word document. I then want to navigate to that bookmark, so that I can update the text inside the rectangle.

I use this code to navigate to the bookmark. This works well when bookmarks are inside other non-text areas, such as tables and charts:

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="RectangleBookmarkName"
```

Unfortunately, I get the error "Word cannot find the requested bookmark".

Any ideas about why this bookmarking technique doesn't appear to work with shapes? Or am I missing something?

(I can navigate to the bookmark manually through the Word bookmarks interface, so the bookmark is definitely there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RectangleBookmarkName").Select
```